# How to Combine Rows of Text in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by, concatenation

I have a table with two columns and i want to combine the text with the same id

```
import pandas as pd
df = DataFrame({'id':[101453,101465,101478,101453,101465,101465], 'text' :['this','is','a','test','string','one']})
```

I need a result like this:

```
df = DataFrame({'id':[101453,101465,101478], 'text':['this test','is string one','a']})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` `join`:

```
print (df.groupby('id')['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index())
       id           text
0  101453      this test
1  101465  is string one
2  101478              a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['id'] = sorted(list(set(df['id'])))
```

set() removes all equal elements. Then return it to list(). And sort it if you need.